# Lync Edge Server Installation

Tags: lync-2010

Recently we got the Lync server installed, we have added users and all. This deployment is based on a single-company environment with approx 500 users, the 30% of this users are remote, who will access Lync Externally as well as a few customers. Now we are in the process of getting it external, as far as i've understood the documentation, the Edge server would be another deployment of the lync server on a separate box, If so would anybody know what would be this server requirements? I've been looking for Lync server requirements but It's not clear to me if this will be a separate install

Comment: Please elaborate on some specifics such as, # of users; # of companies you're hoping to connect with; etc. All of these effect what server requirements you might need. For official guidelines you can see the Microsoft for minimum requirements.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did find some documentation about the requirements for the Edge components, there are 2 articles that are extremely helpful:

Hardware requirements:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg412931(v=ocs.14).aspx

Network requirements:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg425891(v=ocs.14).aspx